# Kip Thorne's time traveling wormhole and conservation of energy

Tags: time-dilation, wormholes

Using this article as a basis: https://www.space.com/28000-physicist-kip-thorne-wildest-theories.html

So you build a wormhole, put one end in your backyard (for convenience your backyard is on an planet(oid) that is as close to non-moving as you can determine it) and put the other in a space-ship. You launch yourself and speed up to near lightspeed. Your wife goes to the backyard, and due to relativity (I assume) the end of the wormhole in the spaceship keeps experiencing time slower allowing for someone who enters it from the space-ship to travel back in time.

Now your wife wants to give you a hug, so she steps into the wormhole onto your ship. She goes from effectively zero speed to near lightspeed. What's going to happen to the poor woman? If you want, you can replace "wife" with "mother in law" to avoid any moral problems ;).

Comment: Why are you assuming it's possible to increase the distance between two ends of a wormhole after it's formed?

Comment: @probably_someone because a man waaaaay smarter than me with knowledge about wormholes, relativity and special relativity thinks it's possible and apparently the scientific.community takes it seriously and discusses it. You could read the article or look it up.